# Rails Mobile App: Inline styles better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

We're developing a Rails 3 app that uses mobile_fu to display another version of the views for mobile devices. So far so good. However, the mobile phone doesn't render the styles everytime, often it is necessary to refresh so the actual formatting shows.

We're wondering if delivering the styles inline is a good idea and if yes, what the best way to do it might be. I thought of a File.read of the .css and yield :css block in the layout-haml.

We understand that this is bad for caching, but I am not sure if the mobile browser cache that much either.. Plus it is just a few dozen extra lines anyway.

This is for mobile only, the desktop version works without problems.

Appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Providing some context as to what mobile platforms you're having difficulty with might yield a better answer from the community and would likely be helpful for anyone else struggling with the same devices.

Comment: We have observed this issue on Android, but we did not test any other platforms. Phones were the Moto Droid 1st gen and a latest-gen Sony Experia phone.

Comment: The fact that it's happening in a modern, Webkit based browser is curious; I'm inclined to think there's something else at work here. I'd disable any minification, append a random number to the .css file name to prevent caching, and possibly move the include to the bottom of the markup. These will have a performance hit but they could help you better understand the context of the problem to find a more appropriate solution. Aside from that, if it's not a high traffic site and you find a method that's maintainable for your workflow, including the CSS in the HTML is fine as far as I'm concerned.